# IOS Objective C: Displaying Messages Dilemma

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the end of a game I made I want to display the score, but I can't get the program to do so. I have a function for displaying messages. How would I get the '*_*' in the line below to display what ever the final score happens to be?

```
[self displayMessage:@"Final Score was: ____. Play again?"];
```

-and here is the function it calls

```
-(void) displayMessage: (NSString*) msg

{

    if (alert) return;
    [self stop];
    alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: What is the `if (alert) return;` good for? Make the object local to this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self displayMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Final Score was: %i. Play again?", finalScore]];
```

Where `finalScore` is a variable that stores the final score.